# Running current node.js file

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

How can I run current (open) node.js file in PHPstrom without changing configuration for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable launching from the context menu you need to turn Node.JS support on for this project. To do this, make sure to configure Node.js interpreter and sources first (Settings/JavaScript/Node.js and NPM for PHPStorm7) and then enable both 'Node.js vXXX Core Modules' and 'Node.js Globals' libraries in Settings/JavaScript/Libraries. For PHPStorm 7, this should be enough to enable 'Run ' in ruight-click menu of any .js file. In previous versions, however, only some certain files (with require(), etc.) were recognized as Node.js applications, so this option was not enabled for all javascript files

Answer (score 1):

In PhpStorm 6.0.2. Press `right click` and `run 'current_file_name'`.

Comment: There no such option in PHPstorm 7